# Comparing and retrieving sets of values from a table that exist in another table using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, duplicates

I want to see if any 'rows' from table 1 are contained within table 2 and extract them from table 2 using LINQ.

Sample scenario:

```
table {
   int ID
   int RowID
   int ColumnID
   string cellvalue
}
```

**Table 1**

```
1, 1, 1, A
2, 1, 2, B
3, 2, 1, C
4, 2, 2, D
```

**Representing**

```
A | B
C | D
```

**Table 2**

```
1, 1, 1, X
2, 1, 2, Y
3, 6, 1, A
4, 6, 2, C
5, 8, 1, A
6, 8, 2, B
7, 9, 1, A
8, 9, 2, B
```

**Representing**

```
X | Y
A | C
A | B
A | B
```

So in the example above, (A|B) from table 1 is also in table 2 (A|B) twice.

The result I want from table 2 is:

```
5, 8, 1, A
6, 8, 2, B
7, 9, 1, A
8, 9, 2, B
```

I was trying to use group by into another query and then contains but I got lost. I'm thinking its probably easier if I pivot it to form the actual rows but there's no pivot in LINQ.

I've most likely skipped over something simple, if any one could please lend a hand? It doesn't have to be LINQ if there's a better answer.

Cheers!

Comment: it's not very clear about the rule here, what if you don't have `A|B` in the table 1 but another pair such as `A|D`?, what if you have a match of 3 like `A|B|C`?...

Comment: @KingKing if you had `A|D` in table 1, it would not match anything in table 2. In the case of partial matches, `A|B` in table 1 would match `A|B|C` in table 2 and the full `A|B|C` would need to be retrieved but `A|C|B` or `C|A|B` would not match as the ColumnIDs need to align (but IDs and RowIDs do not need to match between the tables).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know LINQ but SQL query will be:

```
Select T2.Id, T2.RowID, T2.ColumnID, T2.CellValue 
From Table12 T2 
where 
  exists(
    Select 1 From Table1 T1 
      where T1.ID=T2.ID and 
            T1.RowID=T2.RowID and 
            T1.ColumnID=T2.ColunID and 
            T1.CellValue=T2.CellValue
  )
```

Comment: The ID and RowID don't need to match between tables. In the example above, `A|B` in table 1 exists as RowID 1. While `A|B` exists in table 2 as RowID 8 and RowID 9. So this won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

**Alternative 1:**

```
List<Table> table = new List<Table>() { 
    new Table(1, 1, 1, "A"),
    new Table(2, 1, 2, "B"),
    new Table(3, 2, 1, "C"),
    new Table(4, 2, 2, "D")
};

List<string> rowsTable1 = table.GroupBy(x => x.RowID)
                               .Select(x => string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Cellvalue).ToArray()))
                               .ToList();


List<Table> table2 = new List<Table>() { 
    new Table(1, 1, 1, "X"),
    new Table(2, 1, 2, "Y"),
    new Table(3, 6, 1, "A"),
    new Table(4, 6, 2, "C"),
    new Table(5, 8, 1, "A"),
    new Table(6, 8, 2, "B"),
    new Table(7, 9, 1, "A"),
    new Table(8, 9, 2, "B")
};

List<Table> table3 = table2.GroupBy(x => x.RowID)
                           .Where(x => rowsTable1.Contains(string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Cellvalue).ToArray())))
                           .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y))
                           .ToList();
```

It's composing the rows by joining them into a single string separated by ','. It uses this composition to compare them and find those rows on the second table.

This code does not consider the possibility of having the items ordered differently.  But that could be adjusted as needed.

**Alternative 2:**

```
public class Table 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public int RowID{get;set;}
   public int ColumnID{get;set;}
   public string Cellvalue { get; set; }

   public Table(int id, int rowid, int columnid, string cellvalue)
   {
       ID = id;
       RowID = rowid;
       ColumnID = columnid;
       Cellvalue = cellvalue;
   }
}

public class TableRow
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    public TableRow (IGrouping<int,Table> group)
    {
        Values = group.OrderBy(y => y.ColumnID)
                      .Select(y => y.Cellvalue)
                      .ToList();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        TableRow row = obj as TableRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
            if (row.Values != null && row.Values.Count == Values.Count)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Values[i] != row.Values[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}


List<Table> table = new List<Table>() { 
    new Table(1, 1, 1, "A"),
    new Table(2, 1, 2, "B"),
    new Table(3, 2, 1, "C"),
    new Table(4, 2, 2, "D")
};

List<TableRow> rowsTable1 = table.GroupBy(x => x.RowID)
                                 .Select(x => new TableRow(x))
                                 .ToList();

List<Table> table2 = new List<Table>() { 
    new Table(1, 1, 1, "X"),
    new Table(2, 1, 2, "Y"),
    new Table(3, 6, 1, "A"),
    new Table(4, 6, 2, "C"),
    new Table(5, 8, 1, "A"),
    new Table(6, 8, 2, "B"),
    new Table(7, 9, 1, "A"),
    new Table(8, 9, 2, "B")
};

List<Table> table3 = table2.GroupBy(x => x.RowID)
                           .Where(x => rowsTable1.Exists(y=> y.Equals(new TableRow(x))))
                           .SelectMany(x =>  (IEnumerable<Table>)x)
                           .ToList();
```